# SQL Server order by cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is my query, I want the ordering in this order and not alphabetical.

Here is the order I want them in :

```
Foreign,
Out of State,
Texas,
Unknown,
Total Enrollment
```

I used order by cases, but I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '5'

How do I fix it?

Query :

```
declare @Term int = 20172;

select 
    [Category], [Last_Term], [Current_Term], [#Change], [%Change] 
from 
    (select 
         [Category],
         cast(round(((cast(y.Last_Term as float)) * 1), 2) as varchar(10)) as 'Last_Term',
         cast(round(((cast(y.Current_Term as float)) * 1), 2) as varchar(10))   as 'Current_Term',
         cast(round(((cast(y.Current_Term as float) -
                      cast(y.Last_Term as float)) * 1), 2) as varchar(10)) as '#Change', 
         cast(round((((cast(y.Current_Term as float) - 
                       cast(y.Last_Term as float)) / 
                      (cast(y.Last_Term as float))) * 100), 2) as varchar(10)) + '%' as '%Change'
     from
         (select
              Category, 
              Case
                 when year = substring(CAST (@Term- 10  as Varchar(10)),1,4) 
                    then 'Current_Term'
                 when year = substring(CAST (@Term - 20 as Varchar(10)),1,4) 
                    then 'Last_Term'
              End As ACAD_YEAR, 
              a.enroll 
          from
              (select 
                   case 
                      when dh.HOME = 'F' 
                         then 'Foreign' 
                      when dh.HOME = 'O' 
                         then 'Out of State' 
                      when dh.Home = 'I' 
                         then 'texas'
                      when dh.Home = 'U' 
                         then 'UnKnown'
                   end as Category, 
                   (CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD, 1, 4))) - 1 as year, 
                   count(*) as enroll
               from
                   [IR_DW].[dbo].[dw_enrollment_F] d
               inner join 
                   dim_Time t on d.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
               inner join 
                   dim_Home dh on d.HOME_KEY = dh.HOME_KEY
               inner join 
                   dim_Student_Level sl on d.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY = sl.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
               where 
                   ACADEMIC_PERIOD_ALL = @Term - 10 
                   or ACADEMIC_PERIOD_ALL = @Term
               group by 
                   dh.HOME, (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD,1,4))) - 1) a
           ) src 
       PIVOT 
           (SUM(Enroll) FOR ACAD_YEAR in ([Current_Term] , [Last_Term])) y
    ) a
order by
    case 
       when a.[Category] = 'Foreign' then 1 
       when a.[Category] = 'Out of State' then 2 
       when a.[Category] = 'Texas' then 3 
       when a.[Category] = 'Unknown' then 4
```

Comment: I think you missed at least the last row of the query

Comment: There is missing `END` keyword --> CASE WHEN ........ Then 4 **END**

Answer (score 2):

You are missing and `END` though you are missing the `5` case as well...

`when a.[Category] = 'Total Enrollment' then 5`

```
ORDER BY
 case when a.[Category] = 'Foreign' then 1 
      when a.[Category] = 'Out of State' then 2 
      when a.[Category] = 'Texas' then 3 
      when a.[Category] = 'Unknown' then 4
      when a.[Category] = 'Total Enrollment' then 5 --added this
      else 6 --catch all to make anything that fell outside of these categories unsorted afterwards
 end --added here
```

Comment: Depending on OPs data it might be good to point out the ELSE is missing as well.  And because of that if a.Category doesn't meat one of those criteria they would be null in the case expression and therefore be 1st in the result set

Comment: Fair point for sure @Matt. I assumed these were the *only* values in that column. I'll add a line for that